# What is the “My Project” folder in a Visual Studio VB.NET project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I upgraded a Visual Studio 2003 VB.NET project to Visual Studio 2005, and a "My Project" folder was automatically created and added to my project.

What is the purpose of the auto generated folder "My Project"?  This folder is empty, and I would love to get rid of this folder if it's not needed.

Answer (score 3):

This folder stores project Data Sources (Data menu), resources and settings (probably other things too). All of this is configurable through Project menu, Properties... If you aren't using any of those features now, Visual Studio should recreate the folder if you ever start using anything that requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Give the tree of your Solution.
I think that in this directory should be old project, but you probably dont check backup option.